# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type,

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my file structure

[image]

in my index.html I am trying to reference bootstrap as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but when page loads on localhost, i get below on the console log.

```
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3001/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I also tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I have also tried above all combinations with type="text/css" and type="css"

error remains same with type="text/css" and with type="css" error goes but not able to use any bootstrap class.

tried with and without crossorigin="anonymous"

there are similar questions already posted but the same answers don't work, please let me know what am I missing.

below is my css folder.

[image: css folder]

Comment: did you try adding type="text/css" to the tag?

Comment: Yes, I did, nothing changes when use type="tex/css" and with type="css" don't get any error but not able to use any bootstrap class in the html.

Comment: weird, can you show us whats inside the css folder, plus remove the crossorigin="anonymous"

Comment: I have updated my question with css folder screenshot and also tried all the combinations without crossorigin="anonymous"

Comment: No major browser really rejects CSS only because the MIME type is wrong. I suspect you haven't made the obvious check: is whatever web server you're using (Node.js?) actually serving the CSS and not e.g. an HTML error mesage?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get.

Comment: In other words, what can you see when you paste `http://localhost:3001/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css` into your browser's location bar and hit enter?

Comment: I get this "Cannot GET /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"

Comment: this is weird, my issue resolved when I cut paste CSS from bootstrap folder to resource folder.

Comment: Not particularly weird. If the URL doesn't match the asset's location the server won't find it so the browser can't use it. I suspect you have some framework or build system you haven't mentioned that possibly handles assets in some specific way.